# Optimization of optim() in R ( L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn')

Tags: r, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I'm having some trouble using optim() in R to solve for a likelihood involving an integral. I get an error that says "Error in optim(par = c(0.1, 0.1), LLL, method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = c(0,  : L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'". Below is my code:

```
s1=c(1384,1,1219,1597,2106,145,87,1535,290,1752,265,588,1188,160,745,237,479,39,99,56,1503,158,916,651,1064,166,635,19,553,51,79,155,85,1196,142,108,325  
     ,135,28,422,1032,1018,128,787,1704,307,854,6,896,902)


LLL=function (par) {

  integrand1 <- function(x){ (x-s1[i]+1)*dgamma(x, shape=par[1], rate=par[2]) }
  integrand2 <- function(x){ (-x+s1[i]+1)*dgamma(x, shape=par[1],rate=par[2]) }



  likelihood = vector() 

  for(i in 1:length(s1)) {likelihood[i] = 
    log( integrate(integrand1,lower=s1[i]-1,upper=s1[i])$value+ integrate(integrand2,lower=s1[i],upper=s1[i]+1)$value )  
  }

  like= -sum(likelihood)
  return(like)

}




optim(par=c(0.1,0.1),LLL,method="L-BFGS-B", lower=c(0,0))
```

Thanks for your help.

Best,

YM

Comment: Your question is unreadable. Please use the correct method for displaying code.

Answer (score 6):

The objective function evaluated at the lower bounds of the parameters you provided is infinity.

```
LLL(c(0,0))
# [1] Inf
```

That's why `L-BFGS-B` fails. Try a different lower bound, e.g., `c(0.001,0.001)` and you will get a solution.

```
optim(par=c(0.1,0.1),LLL,method="L-BFGS-B", lower=c(0.001,0.001))

$par
[1] 0.6865841 0.0010000

$value
[1] 369.5532

$counts
function gradient 
      14       14 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
[1] "CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F <= FACTR*EPSMCH"
```

To get the 95% confidence intervals for the parameters try this:

```
res <- optim(par=c(0.1,0.1),LLL,method="L-BFGS-B", lower=c(0.005,0.005), hessian=TRUE)
n <- length(s1)
res$par # solution
# [1] 1.900928 0.005000
res$par - 1.96*sqrt(diag(solve(res$hessian)))/n # lower limit for 95% confint
# [1] 1.888152372 0.004963286
res$par + 1.96*sqrt(diag(solve(res$hessian)))/n # upper limit for 95% confint
# [1] 1.913703040 0.005036714
```

refer to this article: http://www.ms.uky.edu/~mai/sta321/MLEexample.pdf

Comment: @sandipan and Bhas  Thanks to you both for answering. Do you also know how I can output the hessian matrix so I can compute the confidence intervals for the 2 gamma parameters? I tried adding "hessian=TRUE" in optim() and would get: Error in optim(par = c(0.1, 0.1), LLL, method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = c(0.001,  : 
  non-finite finite-difference value [2]

Comment: @Y.Ma to compute hessian the second difference needs to be calculated, that evaluates to infinity with the lower bounds used, we need to use slightly higher lower bounds for the parameters, updated the code.